# Convert image as the array of numbers to another compact format (e.g. PNG) in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, png

I'm a newcomer in js and going to send an image from the client-side to the server. The image I have is an array of numbers and sending it as JSON is bandwidth inefficient! 
I'm looking for a js library to compress the image on the browser and send it with a reduced size. Is it a feasible solution? 
I appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean with "is an array of numbers"? All images are arrays of numbers. If you are using images for transferring *data*, you must not compress it (as an image, lossless compression is ok of course). Because then your data is modified. Also converting it to an image adds the image header which takes more bandwith than sending it as numbers directly.

Comment: By "array of numbers" I was meant something like "getContext('2D').getImageData()' output. I think the suggested answer (Compressorjs.js) is what I was looking for! Thank you all!

Comment: Ah, ok. So it truely is an image. Then my comment was useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Compressorjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs) May do the job you need, hope that helps.